# Wordpress changable text in custom html

Tags: php, html, wordpress, custom-fields

I have a custom page (page-news.php) and I styled it. Now I need to change some texts, and I dont want to do this in hardcoded page-news.php but I want to be able to change that in Wordpress, without go to code. Did you have maybe some ideas how to do this?

Here is visualization of how I think it should work (the only thing I can change would be white custom-text with section-1,section-2 and section-3) and I will be do this in wp-admin > pages >news:

[image]

Any ideas? I will be grateful for answer

Comment: A very nice solution is to use this plugin called ACF :

[ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)

With that, you can create custom fields and assign them to posts - pages - categories and many other options. It's easy to use and there are a lot of features and even more if you get the PRO version.

Comment: thank you very much, this is what I needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin. After installation, you can create custom fields and define their types. In your case, you should create 3 editor field or textarea and attach them to you page. When you visit `wp-admin>pages>news` you'll see these fields. Use `get_field($fieldSlug)` in your page template to show the values.